# Unlock a file download via callback

Tags: routes

pls I want to control a file access to download, a user will download the file only if a test condition is true. .... there is going to be an execution of a callback url from an external site, and my site will receive a signal then will unlock the file, so I use my site IP address as a test condition... if Server_remote address of my site is = the $external callback IP address, then....unlock the file, how do I proceed on that?

if you have a better idea of implementing this, let me know too.

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a case for

1. Private file mode on a file field
2. A custom [hook_file_download](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7)